# Portion of code not executed in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ImageAnalyses Controller where I'd like to execute some code just after **ImageAnalysis** is instantiated but before @image_analysis is saved. Although the controller is successfully creating an instance of ImageAnalysis it's not executing the intermediate code below.

**My controller:**

```
#image_analyses_controller.rb

def create
 @image_analysis = ImageAnalysis.new(image_analysis_params)


 # Start of not executed code
 @client = Aws::Rekognition::Client.new
 @image_analysis.gallery.attachments do |attachment|
   resp = @client.detect_labels(
           image:
              { s3_object: {
                bucket: "my-bucket",
                name: attachment.content.path,
              },
            }
         )

   high_labels = resp.labels.select { |label| label.confidence > 80 }

   high_labels.each do |label|
    ImageLabel.create(
      name: label.name,
      image_url: attachment.content.path,
      image_analysis_id: @image_analysis.id
    )
   end
 end
 # End of not executed code

 respond_to do |format|
  if @image_analysis.save
    format.html { redirect_to @image_analysis, notice: 'Image analysis was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @image_analysis }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @image_analysis.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Interestingly no exceptions are raised and the server log only registers the creation of the ImageAnalysis object with nothing that points me to an error.

I've tried to pass that chunk of code to a method in the model and calling it from the controller with the same results. Could you advise on why this may be happening?

Comment: Can you post the content of  `image_analysis_params` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the `.each` in the line where you have to iterate the `@image_analysis.gallery.attachments`.

Something like this:

```
 @image_analysis.gallery.attachments.each do |attachment|
   resp = @client.detect_labels(
           image:
              { s3_object: {
                bucket: "my-bucket",
                name: attachment.content.path,
              },
            }
         )

   high_labels = resp.labels.select { |label| label.confidence > 80 }

   high_labels.each do |label|
    ImageLabel.create(
      name: label.name,
      image_url: attachment.content.path,
      image_analysis_id: @image_analysis.id
    )
   end
 end
```

However if `@image_analysis.gallery.attachments` is empty, the code inside the `.each` it wont be executed.

Comment: Oh my god, yes the issue is the missing .each method. Thanks for pointing it out. I need a break!!!